# Excel.Interop DisplayAlerts to false does not handle everything

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

Ok i tried looking on here to find this before, but no luck. The problem I'm having is when two programs try to either save, close, or interact in anyway with a single excel workbook at the same time a dialog box appears.

The dialog boxes says something like "[file path] Is currently in use and can not be accessed."

I have DisplayAlerts set to false, but it will not catch this.

Has anyone else had this problem and have a viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is currently in use is due to OS throwing it up rather than Excel (by itself).

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177478%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

From what I understand, Excel can control alerts that show up during regular working of Excel (such as closing file without saving throws up a dialog, which can be prevented from showing up using `DisplayAlerts`).