# pasting data from my clipboard to a different workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using vb.net to copy a range of data from worksheet "A" using the following code:

```
'Set range of data to be copied
xlRng = xlsheet.Range("A2:k" & IntAmountOfRows)
xlRng.Copy()

'close source
xlWb.Close(False)
xlApp.Quit()
```

But when I do this, it asks the user if it wants to keep the huge amount of data on the clipboard. Is there a way to let the application skip this check? I dont want the user to get any annoying popups when they will press yes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` should help out. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629025/excel-interop-displayalerts-to-false-does-not-handle-everything) for more info. For a VB.net only solution, check [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450632/how-to-disable-warnings-in-visual-studio-for-a-visual-basic-web-deployment-proje).

Comment: @Gutanoth Use your `xlApp` instead of `Application`!